# Azure build pipeline path filter to only include particular file extension

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

I'm working on creating build pipeline in Azure DevOps. I want to trigger it against master branch but only when commit has changes under ***src/Project/tds/Serialization.Master/*** Project - this project contains only .item files
If the commit includes any other files together with .item then this pipeline shouldn't trigger, tried path exclude

***BDD***

***Scenario 1***

Given | I've changes for `src/Project/tds/Serialization.Master/*`

Then  | build pipeline should trigger

***Scenario 2***

Given | I've changes for `src/Project/tds/Serialization.Master/*`

And   | I've changes for `src/Foundation/*`

Then  | build pipeline shouldn't trigger

***Scenario 3***

Given | I've changes for `src/Foundation/*`

Then  | build pipeline shouldn't trigger

```
trigger:
  branches:
   include:
     - master
  paths:
    include:
      - src/Project/tds/Serialization.Master/*
    exclude:
      - src/Foundation/*
```

Comment: I don't see the string `.item` anywhere in that code.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - All the items inside Serialization.Master are items file only

Comment: Have a think about that...... that's not your stated requirement. Might this be a bug in waiting?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure build pipeline path filter to only include particular file extension

If want to use path filter to trigger the build for those particular file-extension files in the folder `Serialization.Master`, you could use following syntax：

```
trigger:
  paths:
    exclude:
    - src/Foundation/*
    include:
    - src/Project/tds/Serialization.Master/*
```

You could check the document [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#push-trigger) for some more details.

Note: Do not forget the keyword `paths`.

Comment: Its like that only just adding branch filter as path filter can't be used with branch filter, do you think moving paths up and then branch filter will do the trick

trigger:
  branches:
   include:
     - master
   paths:
    exclude:
    - src/Foundation/*
    include:
    - src/Project/tds/Serialization.Master/*

Comment: @sumittandon, I do not think moving paths up and then branch filter will do the trick trigger at this moment.

Comment: is there any wild card solution available ?

Comment: @sumittandon, please share the complete trigger settings(branch and path), and what is the situation that you want but cannot achieve? Let me try if there are other solutions to this problem

Comment: i've updated the question. let me know if something is unclear to you

Comment: @sumittandon, Thanks for you quickly and detail reply. Scenario 1 and scenario 3 are achievable, but scenario 2 cannot be achieved. It is contradictory to Scenario 1 and scenario 3.